# Are Rhyming, Alliterative Verse etc. forms of linguistic Error Detection/Correction Schemes?

Tags: historical-linguistics, grammar

- [Rhyme (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme)
- [Alliterative verse (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliterative_verse)
- [Metre - Poetry (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry))

Mechanisms such as these appear to help lower information corruption during long range communication, especially during pre-writing eras. It helps the reciter narrow down the possibilities of successive words/sentances.

Are these generally recognized as forms of [error detection and correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction)?

Is there any formal work in this area? Any analysis of linguistic and/or brain evolution?

It seems implied by in this section: [Oral tradition (Transmission)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_tradition#Transmission).

Comment: These are not just error correction codes; they're sources of predictable redundancy, like the vast majority of language phenomena. Language is phonological, and so is language memory; hence aural mnemonics of all kinds have been always prominent in human experience. Poetry is far more structured than simply rhyme and alliteration -- even a short poem like Williams' "Red Wheelbarrow" has layer after layer of phonological (and grammatical, and lexical) structure. See [Ross's analysis of it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Languagesaspoems.pdf), for instance.